# The function AnalogWrite is outputting less voltage than digitalWrite on my board

Tags: analogwrite, digitalwrite

I can't figure out why the output voltage of `analogWrite(255)` is less than the voltage of `digitalWrite(255)`. My code and an image of my setup are below. Some other useful information is that I am using the NodeMCU by HiLetgo, 3.3k ohm resistors with the meters, and that the meters use 1mA of current DC at full scale. Thanks for your help!

```
int pPressure       = D2;
int pPrecipProb     = D1;
int pWindSpeed      = D0;

int mTemperature;
int mHumidity;
int mPressure;
int mPrecipProb;
int mWindSpeed;
int mAlert;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pPrecipProb,   OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pWindSpeed,    OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pPressure,     OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN,   OUTPUT);     // Initialize the LED_BUILTIN pin as an output
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
    mPressure           = (int) constrain(mPressure + 1, 0, 255);
    mPrecipProb         = (int) constrain(mPrecipProb + 1,     0, 255 );
    mWindSpeed          = (int) constrain(mWindSpeed + 1,     0, 255 );

    if(mPressure == 255)
    {
      mPressure = 0;
      mPrecipProb = 0;
      mWindSpeed = 0;
    }

    digitalWrite(pPressure,      HIGH   );
    analogWrite(pPrecipProb,    255 );
    analogWrite(pWindSpeed,     mWindSpeed  );


    delay(10);                    

}
```

[image: Left]

Left: AnalogWrite(255)

Middle: DigitalWrite(HIGH)

Right: the other one that cycles

Comment: Have you tried swapping the meters/resistors?

Comment: Those analog meters may be loading (drawing enough current to cause the voltage to droop) the "analog" output.  The digital output likely has a higher drive ability.  I don't know this for sure, so I'm not putting it as an answer.

Comment: @slightlynybbled: `analogWrite()` on a ESP8266 performs (software) PWM on a normal digital output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, do something simpler, and eliminate possible causes.

1. Are you *certain* the NodeMCU's CPU is an 8bit PWM? If it were
   9bits, it would read about 50% full scale, and 10bits would be about
   25% of digitalWrite (which is what I think I can see on the photo).
2. Swap the analogue meters around, and see if the difference is consistent
   with the pin, or consistent with the meters.
3. Use a digital multimeter (DMM) to measure voltage. It should be a
   small load. So this should eliminate, or identify, the analogue
   meters as a culprit.

If there is still a difference in voltage, do the NodeMCU equivalent of:

```
void setup() {
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT);  // a pin capable of analogOut and DigitalOut
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
  analogWrite(9, 255);  // a pin capable of analogOut and DigitalOut

  delay(100);
}
```

Then swap 9 and 10.

If the DMM shows the analogue output is consistently lower, then go back and check that PWM is 8 bits, and the device output range for PWM is the same output voltage as digitalWrite to a GPIO.

Comment: ESP8266's default PWM resolution is actually [10 bits](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/doc/reference.md#analog-output), which would be consistent with the 25% output shown in the picture.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - Ah ha! That was my main suspicion, but I haven't seen a proper data sheet for it.

Comment: Eh, the ESP8266 datasheet isn't particularly enlightening. PWM has to be done in software so you'd have to look at the core documentation instead.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - thank you, that clarifies things. I thought I had read that all (most?) pins could supply PWM, but I hadn't realised it was soft. So I was looking for the wrong information.

Comment: The 10 bit solution worked! I simply switched out the 255 with 1023. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3242816 - You are welcome. If it answers your question, I'd appreciate you accepting my answer. Not only do I get more points ;-), it also marks in the question list that an answer has been accepted, which may help some of the community. I don't know, but web search engines might also pick up the 'answered' flag. However, I'd hope search engines do a good job of indexing ee.se anyway. While editing this, you have. Thank you!